# MongoDB, Node and Express return all collections that don't exist in a separate collection that has a large amount of data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've been pulling my hair out for weeks over this one.

I have a collection (this is a cut down version):

```
const SubscriberSchema = new Schema({
  publication: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "publicationcollection" },
  buyer: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "buyercollection" },
  postCode: { type: String },
  modifiedBy: { type: String },
  modified: { type: Date }
});
```

I also have a collection containing the 1.75 million UK Postcodes

```
const PostcodeSchema = new Schema({
  postcode: { type: String }
});
```

What I want to do is to return any record in the Subscriber collection which doesn't exist within the Postcode collection.

When I try a very simple aggregation using Mongoose on anything >100 records in the Subscriber collection, I'm getting either a timeout or a >16MB return error.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
router.get(
  "/badpostcodes/:id",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const errors = {};
    Subscriber.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          publication: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),
          postCode: { "$ne": null, $exists: true }
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          'from': 'postcodescollections',
          'localField': 'postCode',
          'foreignField': 'postcode',
          'as': 'founditem'
        }
      },
      // {
      //   $unwind: '$founditem'
      // },
      {
        $match: {
          'founditem': { $eq: [] }
        }
      }
    ], function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        if (result.length > 0) {
          res.json(result);
        } else {
          res.json("0");
        }
      }
    })
  }
);
```

The unwind didn't seem to do anything but it's commented out to show I tried to use it.

I've also tried using a pipeline on the lookup instead but that didn't work, similar to the following (sorry, I don't have my original code attempt so this is from memory only):

```
        $lookup: {
          'from': 'postcodescollections',
          'let': { 'postcode': "$postCode" },
          'pipeline': [
            {
              '$match': {
                'postcode': { $exists: false }
              }
            },
            {
              '$unwind': "$postCode"
            }
          ],
          'as': 'founditem'
        }
```

Thanks in advance so I can hopefully retain some hair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a match on all postcodes that don't match and then unwinding those - that will be a 1.75m documents for each subscriber! The syntax in `$lookup` is also incorrect I think.

I think you can try something like the following - adjust accordingly for your data:

Do a `$lookup` to find a matching postcode in postcodes, then do a match to filter those subscribers that that don't have any `founditem` elements: `"founditem.0": {$exists: false}`

See an example:

```
db.getCollection("subscribers").aggregate(
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
                postCode: { "$ne": null, $exists: true }
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $project: { 
                _id: 1,
                postCode: 1
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $lookup: {
                      from: "postcodescollections",
                      let: { p: "$postCode" },
                      pipeline: [
                        {
                          $match: {
                              $expr:
                                {
                                    $eq: ["$$p","$postcode"] }
                              }

                        },
                        { $project: { _id: 1 } }
                      ],
                      as: "founditem"
                    }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $match: {
                "founditem.0": {$exists: false}
            }
        },

    ]
);
```

Comment: Thank you! Ok, I've tried many versions of this and unfortunately it hasn't worked. Your original $$p caused a timeout. If I removed one $ it returned blank founditems for every record

Comment: @fendify No prob. I have tested the above and usage of the $$ is as per [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#syntax) to access the defined variable in the `let` stage. Are you saying the answer didn't work?

Comment: It didn't, no, unfortunately. Can you please edit as per my original models just in case I'm coding it incorrectly? "postCode" in the Subscriber model and "postcode" in the postcodescollections model? I have tried multiple versions though and completely agree that I should be returning matches and then filtering non-matches though.

Comment: How many subscriber records are you running this against? If I try on minimal documents (<100) this works fine, but I am working with >13000 subscriber records and it's timing out every time. Do I need to add more indexes to the table other than the main ObjectID? This really is so frustrating because I could make this query so easily with a T-SQL join that returns results in seconds! I appreciate it may just be my lack of knowledge of document based databases but I chose Mongo as it's out-performed SQL on any other query I've made..

Comment: I just loaded 2m postcodescollections, 15000 subscribers and left 1000 subscribers with no matching postcode. Indexes created on postcode. Returns in 2.4s on my machine. You need the indexes, relevant projections in the pipeline stages and should be able to resolve this.

Comment: Fantastic! That worked! I had an index on the postCode field in the Subscribers collection, not the postcodes collection. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Great stuff. That field name is going to be a pain later on again.